# Proving a ODE of order N has N linearly independent solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

So, how this was proven to me was using the Wronskian, by showing that if there were $k$ solutions such that $k>N$ then the Wronskian is zero and therefore the solutions are linearly dependent. My issue with this was, to me, nothing about this proves that there can't be $k$, such that $k<N$, solutions. Did I misunderstand something about this proof, or is there a need for some complementary proof to show that there can't be $k<N$ solutions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just any homogenous linear ODE, not anything more specific than that. As for the vector space question, yes, as far as I'm aware the solutions should form a vector space, but even then, what's stopping them from forming a vector space with one less element in the basis?

Comment: @JCAA : You could just as easily just solve the IVP with the canonical basis vectors as initial conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick a point $t_0$ and solve the initial-value problems with $y_i^{(j-1)}(t_0)=\delta_{ij}$, $i,j=1,...,N$, $y^{(0)}=y$. This gives you $N$ solutions that are independent in $t_0$ and thus by the Wronski theory over the whole domain of the solutions.

Any other solution $y$ can be linearly combined in $t=t_0$ from the $y_i$ so that equality is established in value and the first $N-1$ derivatives. By the uniqueness property of the existence theorem this linear combination is then equal to $y$ on its whole domain. Thus there is no other independent solution.

Remember, the domain of a solution of a linear ODE is the largest interval containing $t_0$ where all the coefficients are continuous and the leading coefficient is non-zero.

Comment: Hmmm this makes sense, thank you :)